# Java Outbound Adaptor processing

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have created an application that adds inbound adaptors at run time for ftp servers and registers them for removing at a certain stage if needed, this app will pull a csv file from ftp server(s) and place it in my local in a folder having the name of the ftp server, so every server I add will have a separate local folder created and the csv file is saved in it, now this is accomplished smoothly, the second part is I want to change the format of that file and then send it back to the respective server, so basically I need to use outbound adaptor, in this case I would need to create outbound adaptors at run time at the same time when creating inbound adaptor or adding a server, this should be done through controller same as the inbound, I searched for possible solutions and tried a one that is below but did not work or did not perform any sending of files to destination, any solution on how I can accomplish this?
In the configuration class I added the below:

```
public IntegrationFlow ftpOutboundFlow(Branch myBranch){

    return IntegrationFlows.from(OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)
            .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch), FileExistsMode.FAIL)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                    .remoteFileSeparator("/")
                    //.fileNameExpression("BEY/FEFOexportBEY.csv")
            .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath()))
            .get();

}

@MessagingGateway
public interface MyGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)
    void sendToFtp(File file);

}



 @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow ftpOutboundChannel() {

        return IntegrationFlows.from(OUTBOUND_CHANNEL)
                .publishSubscribeChannel(p -> p
                        .subscribe(t -> t.handle(System.out::println)))
                /*.transform(p -> {
                    LOG.info("Outbound intermediate Channel, message=rename file:" + p);
                    return p;
                })*/
                .channel(new NullChannel())
                .get();
    }
```

And in the Controller class

```
@RequestMapping("/branch/showbranch/{id}")
    public String getBranch (@PathVariable String id, Model model){
       model.addAttribute("branch", branchService.getById(Long.valueOf(id)));
       addFlowftp(id);
       addFlowftpOutbound(id);
        return "/branch/showbranch";

}

private void addFlowFtp(String name) {
        branch = branchService.getById(Long.valueOf(name));
        System.out.println(branch.getBranchCode());
        IntegrationFlow flow = ftIntegration.fileInboundFlowFromFTPServer(branch);
        this.flowContext.registration(flow).id(name).register();
    }

    private void addFlowftpOutbound(String name) {
        branch = branchService.getById(Long.valueOf(name));
        System.out.println(branch.getBranchCode());
        IntegrationFlow flow = ftIntegration.ftpOutboundFlow(branch);
      //  this.flowContext.registration(flow).id(name).register();
        myGateway.sendToFtp(new File("BEY/FEFOexportBEY.csv"));
    }
```

Here is what I get in the consol as error when I enable the register before sending the file:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An IntegrationFlow 'IntegrationFlowRegistration{integrationFlow=StandardIntegrationFlow{integrationComponents={org.springframework.integration.ftp.inbound.FtpInboundFileSynchronizer@aadab28=98.org.springframework.integration.ftp.inbound.FtpInboundFileSynchronizer#0, org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean@aa290b3=stockInboundPoller, org.springframework.integration.transformer.MethodInvokingTransformer@e5f85cd=98.org.springframework.integration.transformer.MethodInvokingTransformer#0, 98.channel#0=98.channel#0, org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean@319dff2=98.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0}}, id='98', inputChannel=null}' with flowId '98' is already registered.
An existing IntegrationFlowRegistration must be destroyed before overriding.
```

After my second trial where I removed the registration from the first method and only tried with the second method but nothing was sent to the FTP:

```
GenericMessage [payload=BEY\FEFOexportBEY.csv, headers={id=43cfc2db-41e9-0866-8e4c-8e95968189ff, timestamp=1542702869007}]
2018-11-20 10:34:29.011  INFO 13716 --- [nio-8081-exec-6] f.s.s.configuration.FTIntegration        : Outbound intermediate Channel, message=rename file:BEY\FEFOexportBEY.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform `this.flowContext.registration(flow).id(name).register();` before sending the file via `myGateway.sendToFtp(new File("BEY/FEFOexportBEY.csv"));`.

That's first.

Other concern I see in your code that you have a `ftpOutboundChannel` bean for an `IntegrationFlow` which is subscribed to the same `OUTBOUND_CHANNEL`. If that one is not declared as a `PublishSubscribeChannel`, then you'll end up with the round-robin distribution. And I believe you would like to have file sent to the FTP and logged. So, indeed you need to declare that channel as a `PublishSubscribeChannel`.

You don't have any error because that `OUTBOUND_CHANNEL` has your `ftpOutboundChannel` `IntegrationFlow` as subscriber.

Comment: Thanks for the help, If I enable this.flowContext.registration(flow).id(name).register(); it is telling that the id is already registered when I add a new FTP server, this is because I have a method called addFlowFtp that is registering the server when adding it for inbound flow, so not able to do it twice, any solution for that? I updated the code as well to show the other method, I also updated method ftpOutboundChannel() to have PublishSubscribeChannel, can you please let me know that is fine now as well? some how new with Spring Integration

Comment: I tried as well to comment the registration in the first method and ran the app, then tried to add a branch, it did not FTP the csv file to destination folder, it did not do anything, I updated at the end of the coding above with the new consol that I got@Artem Bilan

Comment: Can you please help as well here @Gary Russell

Comment: Your `OUTBOUND_CHANNEL` is not a `PublishSubscribeChannel` yet, so your `ftpOutboundChannel()` still wins to get a message from the gateway.

Comment: Is there any example where I reference and sort my issue out?cause I'm not sure how I can make my OUTBOUND_CHANNEL as  PublishSubscribeChannel although I have  added it in ftpOutboundChannel()...@Artem Bilan

Comment: You need to have a ` PublishSubscribeChannel` `@Bean` with that `OUTBOUND_CHANNEL` name. What you did in the `ftpOutboundChannel()` `IntegrationFlow` is fully not related.

Comment: Although it is fully not clear why do you need to create those flows dynamically. You can consider to use a `DelegatingSessionFactory` which will resolve a target `SessionFactory` at runtime against a request message. And you still just need to use a single flow with a single `Ftp.outboundAdapter()`. You `branch` can be used to set a `threadKey` on that `DelegatingSessionFactory`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-dsf

Comment: The project is two parts, first which I finished with the help of Gary, it is a Spring MVC with Spring Integration where at run time I add an FTP server, it will pull a csv file from that FTP server to my local using inbound adaptor, second part, I need to process this csv and generate a new format file .csv, then send it back from my local to the corresponding server, so if I add Branch X then I pull a file from there process it and send it back to X, the ftp server(s) that I add are saved in PostgreSQL DB from a webpage using Thymeleaf, hope I clarified my proj @Artem Bilan

Comment: How does it work with that `ftpOutboundChannel` bean? BTW why do you call `IntegrationFlow` as a channel. It is confusing

Comment: To be honest I'm checking some online solutions and trying to config them to meet my needs, it is confusing to me as well, as I created the inbound dynamically at runtime, I want to do the same for the outbound when I add a server, so when I create the inbound it creates the outbound as well, it will poll the local folder and when a new file is created from the inbounded file it will send it to the server, if all my outbound config does not make  sense I'm fine with removing it and create a correct one or modify it to work correctly @Artem Bilan

Comment: Also you still don't register the result of the `IntegrationFlow flow = ftIntegration.ftpOutboundFlow(branch);` and just try to use a gateway.

Comment: If I try registering it is giving me error since I'm registering the same one when creating the inbound, should I register with something like name+"o" just change the name and then remove it when I delete a server? Gateway is new to me so maybe I will give it a search to see how that is properly used @Artem Bilan

Comment: If you don't register dynamic flow, there is nothing going to happen afterwards. If you definitely need to have that outbound flow as well, then you don't have choice unless register it in the `IntegrationFlowContext`. If there is a clash with names, then consider to use different names. Your use-case is so hard to understand. You have DB with finite set of servers, so iterate over that and declare beans during startup of the application and don't do any dynamic registrations. To hard to follow with your logic.

Comment: Sorry if not making it clear, I understand the concern you are sharing about delegations and rotation, that happens if I have the servers already in my DB, definitely that would be the solution, but for my case I do not have them in the DB because I will continually add and remove, so the solution will be starting with one server then later on the business manager would like to add more servers or remove a one depending on the business needs,so not static number of branches so that I say ok I have all those and I want to poll them...@Artem Bilan

Comment: I was able to get this sorted out after creating message channel returning PublishSubscribeChannel()...is there a way I can delete the file that I sent to FTP from my local and keep on watching my local folder for any new file to send it to the ftp server to replace the old one? So basically I want to poll my local folder to send a new file generated there and then delete it from my local..thanks @Artem Bilan

Comment: This doesn’t sound like related to the question in the thread. Please, consider to accept the current one and raise a new SO thread with details about this your delete concern.